# Plaintext with 'T' and 'E' alphabets missing and encrypted with Vigenere Cipher

Tags: encryption, vigenere

I wrote the normal code to decrypt a Vigenere cipher encrypted text without knowing the key. But that won't work for this are two of the alphabets are missing and that would mess up the frequency analysis. Any idea on how to go about decrypting it?

Comment: A please remove the ciphertext to comply with rules so we can focus on actual question

Answer (score 1):

frequency analysis works just fine even without a few common letters. In fact you don't even need to know the frequency in the underlying alphabet it is sufficient that it is far from uniform. You can rotate the columns so as to make the frequencies in each match.
Alternatively using an English bi-gram frequency table you can break this quickly even without two letters.

Do you know if the letters were removed from plain text in preprocessing or is this a clever text without these? it makes no difference for first method but some if you bring in external frequency tables.

Comment: It is a clever text without the letters. I tried doing it using Kasiski method but it's not getting the key properly.

Comment: You found the length? Does it seem reasonable? Are you matching each column with english frequencies? or with the previous columns? How much data do you have in each column? is it enough for frequency analasis? if not you must move to bigram or trigram frequencies.

Comment: Also i you know for a fact T and E are missing you can actually use this to break the cipher easily, but this might be "cheating"